# how to fix : Document type: Parent Information, Operation: create V12

Tags: odoo-12

plz i need help when i want to create a new parent or school i have this problem : " The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Parent Information, Operation: create)  (Records: [6], User: 2)  "
  NB : I use account Admin and all access rights in this account but same error odoo V12

Hello , plz i need help when i want to create a new parent or school i have this problem : 
" The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Parent Information, Operation: create)  (Records: [6], User: 2) "

NB : I use account Admin and all access rights in this account but same error odoo V12[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ukOU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Till odoo11 record rules are not applying on super admin but from odoo12 record rules start applying on admin and according to your record rule it simply says that if partner id is same or user id is same only those can create school.parent that is applying to admin also that's why this error is coming.